# Proving whether ~ is an equivalence class

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

So I have the following question. I basically have to decide whether or not it is an equivalence relation on the reals R. If yes, then prove it and describe [2/3] (the equivalence class). If no, prove that it is not:

"x~y means x-y is an integer."

My understanding on this topic is crude!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you done? This is a very mechanical problem with three properties to check. Were you able to verify any of them?

Comment: "$\sim$" is an equivalence relation. An equivalence class is the set of all $x$ and $y$ for which $x \sim y$.

Comment: @qbert So, if I wanted to proof that this was reflexive, do I just take 2/3 - 2/3 =0, and from there conclude that it's reflexive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to verify the three basic properties of equivalence relations. These are the following:

1) *Reflexivity: For all reals $x$, $x \sim x$*.

2) *Symmetry: Whenever $x \sim y$, then $y \sim x$*.

3)*Transitivity: Whenever $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$, then $x \sim z$*.

Remark: It is important that the above is checked **for all possible values of each variable**. In your comment, you said you were checking it only for $\frac 23$, this is incorrect.

So we will verify each one:

1) $x \sim x$ is true since $x-x=0$, which is an integer **for all values of $x$, not just $\frac 23$**.

2) $x \sim y$ means that $x-y$ is an integer. But then $y-x = (-1)(x-y)$ is also an integer, so that $y \sim x$ is also true, **for all values of $x$ and $y$**.

3) If $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$ are true, then this means that $x -y $ and $y-z$ are integers. But then, $(x-y) + (y-z) = (x-z)$ is also an integer. This means that $x \sim z$. Again, the above is true for all values of $x,y,z$.

Hence, our relation is an equivalence relation.

The definition of equivalence class of an element $x$ is all $y$ such that $x \sim y$. So an element $k$ is related to $\frac{2}{3}$ if and only if $k-\frac{2}{3}$ is an integer.

Thus, in set notation, we can write $\left[\frac 23 \right] = \left\{ k + \frac 23 : k \in \mathbb Z \right\}$. It can also be written as $\{ \ldots, \frac{-7}3,\frac{-4}{3}, \frac {-1}3,\frac 23,\frac 53,\frac 83,\ldots\}$.

---

In our case, it so happens that this equivalence relation has a  special name : $\mathbb R$ is a group under addition, and $\mathbb Z$ is a subgroup. Knowing this much itself, it is  easy to see, more generally for $H \leq G$  groups, that  $x \sim y \iff x-y \in H$ is an equivalence relation on $G$, and the set of equivalence classes $\{[x]\}$ is denoted $\frac GH$, called the quotient of $G$ by $H$. It is not always a group, in fact precisely when $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. In our case, we are actually dealing with $\mathbb R \over \mathbb Z$, and it turns out that this is a group since $\mathbb R$ is abelian, so every subgroup is normal. The equivalence classes are denoted $[x]$, and we have $\{x\} = x+\mathbb Z$